# jQuery autocomplete runs every pageLoad

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jQuerys autocomplete. When page is load below ajax run automaticly. But i want to do this if anyone keydown this textbox. How can i change ?

```
 $('#txtFirmaAdlari').autocomplete({
                      source: function (request, response) {
                          $.ajax({
                              url: '/Fatura/GetFirma/',
                              dataType: "json",
                              cache: false,
                              traditional: true,
```

Comment: Refer this example http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote and view its source code to get some idea

Comment: Try using hte URL directly like:    source:"/Fatura/GetFirma/"